# Windows Phone 8 Button text animation - C# / XAML

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, blend

I'm trying to animate the text inside a Button object so it would look like [this Android boot text](http://i1230.photobucket.com/albums/ee496/JaeKar99/BasicBoot-tab.gif).

Does anyone know how or if it's even possible to do this on Windows Phone?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have blend? This question is to general for stack overflow. Please define your question more before posting here. Thanks

Comment: Agree with AMR here. But, given you have Blend or some knowledge of Animations, you could create an OpacityMask and animate the TranslateTransform of the RenderTransform of the button border. You'd have to create your own Button Template though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the very solution you were searching for, I might be wrong but according to my studies and experience this is what I have made for you.

First of all edit a button control, in that I have created the story board and animated the content, then I used control story board action behavior to call that story board on Loaded trigger.

Here is the XAML of my edited Button including the story board I created.

```
<Style x:Key="animatedText" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="1"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger>
                                <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hope this is your solution.

Happy Coding!